# Mid-Stream Changing Configuration with Check-Pointed Spark Stream

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have a Spark streaming / DStream app like [this](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#checkpointing):

```
// Function to create and setup a new StreamingContext
def functionToCreateContext(): StreamingContext = {
  val ssc = new StreamingContext(...)   // new context
  val lines = ssc.socketTextStream(...) // create DStreams
  ...
  ssc.checkpoint(checkpointDirectory)   // set checkpoint directory
  ssc
}

// Get StreamingContext from checkpoint data or create a new one
val context = StreamingContext.getOrCreate(checkpointDirectory, functionToCreateContext _)

// Do additional setup on context that needs to be done,
// irrespective of whether it is being started or restarted
context. ...

// Start the context
context.start()
context.awaitTermination()
```

Where my context uses a configuration file where I can pull items with methods like `appConf.getString`. So I actually use:

```
val context = StreamingContext.getOrCreate(
    appConf.getString("spark.checkpointDirectory"), 
    () => createStreamContext(sparkConf, appConf))
```

where `val sparkConf = new SparkConf()...`.

If I stop my app and change configuration in the app file, these changes are not picked up unless I delete the checkpoint directory contents. For example, I would like to change `spark.streaming.kafka.maxRatePerPartition` or `spark.windowDurationSecs` dynamically. (**EDIT**: I kill the app, change the configuration file and then restart the app.) How can I do dynamically change these settings or enforce a (EDITED WORD) configuration change without trashing my checkpoint directory (which is about to include checkpoints for state info)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I do dynamically change these settings or enforce a configuration change without trashing my checkpoint directory?

If dive into the code for `StreamingContext.getOrCreate`:

```
def getOrCreate(
    checkpointPath: String,
    creatingFunc: () => StreamingContext,
    hadoopConf: Configuration = SparkHadoopUtil.get.conf,
    createOnError: Boolean = false
  ): StreamingContext = {
    val checkpointOption = CheckpointReader.read(
      checkpointPath, new SparkConf(), hadoopConf, createOnError)
    checkpointOption.map(new StreamingContext(null, _, null)).getOrElse(creatingFunc())
}
```

You can see that if `CheckpointReader` has checkpointed data in the class path, it uses `new SparkConf()` as a parameter, as the overload doesn't allow for passing of a custom created `SparkConf`. By default, `SparkConf` will load any settings declared either as an environment variable or passed to the classpath:

```
class SparkConf(loadDefaults: Boolean) extends Cloneable with Logging {

  import SparkConf._

  /** Create a SparkConf that loads defaults from system properties and the classpath */
  def this() = this(true)
```

So one way of achieving what you want is instead of creating a `SparkConf` object in the code, you can pass the parameters via `spark.driver.extraClassPath` and `spark.executor.extraClassPath` to `spark-submit`.

Answer (score 2):

Do you create your Streaming Context the way the docs suggest, by using `StreamingContext.getOrCreate`, which takes a previous `checkpointDirectory` as an argument?

```
// Function to create and setup a new StreamingContext
def functionToCreateContext(): StreamingContext = {
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(...)   // new context
    val lines = ssc.socketTextStream(...) // create DStreams
    ...
    ssc.checkpoint(checkpointDirectory)   // set checkpoint directory
    ssc
}

// Get StreamingContext from checkpoint data or create a new one
val context = StreamingContext.getOrCreate(checkpointDirectory, functionToCreateContext _)

// Do additional setup on context that needs to be done,
// irrespective of whether it is being started or restarted
context. ...

// Start the context
context.start()
context.awaitTermination()
```

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#checkpointing

Comment: Yes I did almost the same things that was above. The only major difference is that my `ssc.socketTextStream(...)` is more like `KafkaUtils.createDirectStream` with ssc as a param.

Comment: It took a while to figure this out ... I missed a very subtle point which I needed to fully get the picture. If I use `context.sparkContext.getConf.set("spark.xxxx", "10")`, I can set whatever Spark Conf parameters I need to use (in the spot you suggested). This was the final piece I needed to know.

Comment: I'm going to have to revert because it seems that `...getConf.set()` doesn't seem to change the context on the fly -- I think what Yuval recommends or a yet-to-be-mentioned techniques is going to have to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It can not be done adding/updating spark configurations when you are restoring from checkpoint directory. You can find spark checkpointing behaviour in documentation:

> When the program is being started for the first time, it will create a new StreamingContext, set up all the streams and then call start().
>   When the program is being restarted after failure, it will re-create a StreamingContext from the checkpoint data in the checkpoint directory

So if you use checkpoint directory then on restart of job it will re-create a StreamingContext from checkpoint data which will have old sparkConf.